# Projecting longitude / latitude from shapefile

Tags: shapefile

I have a shapefile with this information embedded:

Projected Coordinate System:

```
CH1903+_LV95
[+proj=somerc +a=6377397.155000 +b=6356078.962818 +x_0=2600000.0 +y_0=1200000.0 +k_0=1.0 +alpha=90.0 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +no_defs]
```

How would I convert a point from this shape (as example:
(2883434.7562500015, 1208358.5424999967, -1.4551915228366852E-11)
to a normal longitude/latitude) ?

Anyone know the correct formula?

Comment: Do you need transformed values in a new field of the attributes table for the same layer or do you need a new layer with the transformed geometries features?

Comment: It's far easier to choose a GIS tool or code library than to code your own.

Answer (score 1):

What you see there is a [PROJ](https://proj.org/faq.html#what-is-the-best-format-for-describing-coordinate-reference-systems) string.

`somerc` is the [Swiss Oblique Mercator](https://proj.org/operations/projections/somerc.html) projection.

You can find all the mathematical details about it in SwissTopo's "[Formulas and constants for the calculation of the Swiss conformal cylindrical projection and for the transformation between coordinate systems](https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/content/swisstopo-internet/en/topics/survey/reference-systems/switzerland/_jcr_content/contentPar/tabs/items/dokumente_publikatio/tabPar/downloadlist/downloadItems/517_1459343190376.download/refsys_e.pdf)" available at https://www.swisstopo.admin.ch/en/knowledge-facts/surveying-geodesy/reference-systems/map-projections.html#documents_publicatio.

Converting the coordinates by yourself using these formulas is a significant undertaking and I would recommend that you use readily available software solutions instead. Good luck!